On chat window when there is no messages,inputarea is on top below header,not in the bottom
I am creating a chat web app for a project and when there is no messages displayed on chat window the inputarea and button appear on top,below header. After every message it get's down till it reach bottom. I want it to be displayed on bottom even if there are no messages.I will provide html,java, and css,to see if anyone can help me?I don't want to use margin-top on input-area because it creates empty space between messages when i have messages displayed. Thanks in advance!


.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat-window {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  resize: none;
  margin-left: 730px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chat_header {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  margin-left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 30%;
  color: #F5D0A9;
  background-color: #4C0B5F;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.chat_msg {
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  max-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: none;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 190px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #4C0B5F;
  color: #F5D0A9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crdts {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 770px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.lgout {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1600px;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SecretChat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wlcmpg.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>SecretChat</h1>



  <h3>Welcome to secretchat.</h3>
  <p>This web app is a test for a project on my IT school to learn how to create chat systems using signal or PGP cryptography to create safe communication platforms.</p>
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="chat-window" id="chat-window">
      <form action="send_message.php" method="post" id="chat-form" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
        <div class="chat_header" id="chatuser">Chat</div>
        <div class="chat_msg"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="receiver" id="receiver" value="">

        <div class="input-area">
          <textarea placeholder="type your message" name="message"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="users-list">
      <ul id="users-list"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>










  <h2 class="crdts">Credits on BPPCDR</h2>

</body>

</html>




Welcome to SO! Please create a minimal example.

What do you mean?

Do you mean share a lighter version of the code?

See [ask] and how to create a [mre] from the site guidance. It should be the shortest code (and any test data) needed to demonstrate the problem. Remove anything not directly relevant.

Okay, sorry guys. Post updated

I have updated your CSS to ensure the input area remains fixed at the bottom of the chat window, regardless of the number of messages present or if the chat window is empty. This adjustment maintains the input area in view, making it more user-friendly for continuous messaging:
.chat_header {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  margin-left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f5d0a9;
  background-color: #4c0b5f;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.input-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}


Thanks for trying to help, but i have tried also to add position absolute on the input-area and once i do this, when i have messages the input-area stays in the same spot and message overflow below input-area. I think it has something to do with the height of the window

@ΓεωργιοςΠαπαδοπουλος There are couple of other things which you also need to fix, i.e., when I opened the webpage this <h2 class="crdts">Credits on BPPCDR</h2> was behind the chat container. Tell me what exactly you need so I'll update my response.

hey,sorry for late feedback, i fixed it. It was the height of chat_msg that was causing this problem. Thanks for your help i appreciate it.

Great, you are welcome.
